# Xpath and CssSelectors for same tag, attributes and elements

Tags: c#, selenium, xpath, css-selectors

I am trying to create Selenium tests for a button that has the same code for 4 buttons(The following html repeats 4 times):

```
    <div class="item">
<div class="head">
   <a class="title caps_style primary-color-text"href="https://www.www.www/link/link-link-complex-api-testing" target="_blank">Rake Athlete Complex API TESTING</a>
</div>
<div class="middle">
   <div class="photo_square">
      <a class="" href="https://www.www.www/link/link-link-complex-api-testing" target="_blank"><img src="/assets/2.png"></a>
   </div>
   <span class="stats">
      <span class="title caps_style votes">salvations</span>
      <span class="amt caps_style primary-color-text">
         <i class="heart"></i><!-- react-text: 58 -->240
         <!-- /react-text -->
      </span>
   </span>
   <div class="stats">
      <span class="title caps_style">Pickles Grazed</span>
      <span class="amt caps_style primary-color-text">
         <span class="fastack"><i class="fastack2x"></i>
         <i class="fainverse"></i></span>
         <i class="usb"></i><!-- react-text: 66 -->184 k<!-- /react-text -->
      </span>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="bottom">
   <span class="snippit">latin fillin text</span>
</div>
<div class="inline-b">
   <div>
      <button class="vote-btn primary-color-background">
      <img src="//www.www.www/assets/pic.png">
      <span class="primary-color-background">Give</span>
      </button>
   </div>
</div>
```

Here is the C# code I am attempting to run for the first button (CssSelector and XPath):

```
driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("button.vote-btn.primary-color-background")).Click();
```

And:

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='Sections-react-component-0']/div/div[3]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[4]/div/button").Click();
```

I am receiving the following error message when I Selenium test:

```
Message: System.InvalidOperationException : unknown error: Element <button class="vote-btn primary-color-background">...</button> is not clickable at point (286, 1233). 
Other element would receive the click: <p>...</p>
      (Session info: chrome=61.0.3163.100)
      (Driver info: chromedriver=2.32.498550
```

Would it be possible to select a specific option using CssSelector? for example using [2] or [4] somewhere in the code?

Comment: 1. for css selector, it has similar feature as xpath's [index]. but more strict than xpath.  in css selector you can use :nth-child(index) index >=1 or nth-of-type(index)  index>=1.  but nth-child() require they have same parent node, but xpath not require.

Comment: from your code, the css selector is right. but you met error: 'element not clickable, other element would receive the click'. this error means there are some things cover the button you want to click, the button on the lower layer,  so the element on top layer will recevie the click.  you can check is there anythong on top the button during running.   if not,  you need to wai the page loading complete, because when page is loading the button position maybe is changing, so you will click on an old point which is not the latest position of the button.

Comment: Why not just use an index?  If there are 4 buttons, then "sameCode[1], sameCode[2], sameCode[3], sameCode[4]".  Obviously that is using xPath, but you can do something similiar in CssSelector, I think it is "sameCode(1)..etc etc"  using nth-child.

Comment: Thanks you two, I will look into this. I'm pretty new to C# and I am still trying to grasp formatting. Also, yong, I have attempted to add a Thread.Sleep(1000) to give the page enough time to load but it still fails with the current code. I'd also like to note that the code was working fine yesterday, I need to get that sticker on my laptop. lol

Answer (score 0):

You should try using "className" selector like,

```
driver.FindElement(By.className("vote-btn")).Click();
```

Or you can also try using "css selector" like,

```
driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(".vote-btn.primary-color-background")).Click();
```

Comment: Thanks Pratik, the issue I'm facing is that I have 4 sections that have the same exact code and I need to find a way to specify which button I want to target. ATM I do not have a way of pointing to each one of them.

Comment: @Lgalan90 Then use driver. **findElements** and use a iterator/loop to get specific button using condition and index value. I hope this solves your issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple sections with the same button - best choice is to go top>down in locator and specify section and find the button in it.

As button[n] tells you nothing which exact button you are looking for. And what will happen if another button will be added? Specify section too, not only button.

And in css locator it's impossible to identify an element by position number.

Example of page with sections will help us much to build efficient locator.

Comment: I have edited my response and will look into nth-child's as mentioned by yong and IamBatman.